# Create multiple "indexed" Julia DataFrames with a for loop

Tags: for-loop, julia, dataframes.jl

I would like to create several Julia DataFrames using a for loop, so that the name of each DataFrame is indexed.

An example I tried (doesn't work of course) :

```
name_list = ["A","B"]
 
for i in list    
   "df$i" = DataFrame()
end
```

What I would like to obtain is 2 empty dataframes named dfA, dfB

Any help would be appreciated

Thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires meta-programming and for this kind of cases is usually not the best way to handle problem. You could do:

```
for i in name_list
    eval(:($(Symbol(:df,i)) = DataFrame()))
end
```

This generates exactly `dfA` and `dfB` as you wanted.

However, normally it would be usually better to create a `Dict`:

```
df = Dict{String, DataFrame}()
for i in name_list
    df[i] = DataFrame()
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and the best practice recommendation. I will adapt my code to use it.